# Normalization produce bad result for mlp

Tags: scikit-learn, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I tried to normalize my data with Sklearn and MinMaxScaler method (0.1, 1)
But the result is very disapointed.
Without MinMax normalization, I was at 78% of accuracy on my problem, and with min max normalization, it fall to 71%.
Do you know what could be the problem ?

My data shape is : [n_samples][1D_vector_of_values]

Here is how I use sklearn for normalize:

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0.1,10))
X = np.array(X)
X_test = np.array(X_test)
X = scaler.fit_transform(X)
X_test = scaler.fit_transform(X_test)
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not always the case normalization will give you good result as without since you are loosing some data by applying this discrimination method. it all depends on the nature of the data.

I'd try to implement standardization instead of range normalization but be careful to use the same same standardization batch for testing and validation. you didn't give us more information about your data but I'd still ask you to implement feature selection after the normalization/standardization.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer!
I'm using a dataset from kaggle on the credit score.
They have shape [age,sex,annual income, monthly bill, ...]. 10 fields in total.
Is there a way to determine when normalization should be applied ?

And what is standardization interest over normalization ?
For feature selection, since i'm using neural net, the nn should do it by itself no ?
Thanks !

Comment: here is a link explains the difference. http://www.benetzkorn.com/2011/11/data-normalization-and-standardization/ As what you said maybe it is important to keep all the features. of course NN can't do this job for you. it is your job to do feature building which will help to build the best model.